# Preventing Duplicate entries in an Access form if the value exists in multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access database with two tables and a form.

The form is linked to one of the tables for data entry purposes.

I have:

- `LIVEDB` which is a table of live customers' info.
- `LIVEDBINPUT` form which inputs information into `LIVEDB`
- `CANCELLATIONDB` which is just a table - when someone cancels, they are simple cut from `LIVEDB` and pasted into `CANCELLATIONDB`.

I have all sorts of rules that prevent duplicates in the `LIVEDBINPUT` form, but I have recently encountered a problem: the `LIVEDBINPUT` form is not preventing duplicates from the `CANCELLATIONDB` table, only the `LIVEDB` table.

I want the form to prevent a telephone number being entered, if the telephone number already appears in either the `LIVEDB` table **OR** the `CANCELLATIONDB` table.

If I could configure a message box to appear that states something like *"this telephone number already exists in `LIVEDB` or `CANCELLATIONDB`"*, and then the option to take the user to that record or delete it, that would be ideal.

I have found loads of information about how to achieve this in multiple columns of one table, but I can't work out or find a way to prevent the duplicates from both tables i.e. for the form to prevent creating a duplicate that already exists in either of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a `UNION` query which yields all records stored in both your `LIVEDB` table and your `CANCELLATIONDB` table, then test for existing records in this query prior to storing new records.

Assuming that your `CANCELLATIONDB` table has an identical structure to your `LIVEDB` table (since you are moving records from one to the other), the `UNION` query could be as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM LIVEDB UNION SELECT * FROM CANCELLATIONDB
```

Comment: Hi yes thanks but I am trying to remove the step of "testing existing records prior to storing new records" as we enter around 100 new records daily this will take some time to query prior to entry each time